# Extract Chrome browser bookmarks in Mavericks, as Chrome is EOL

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Model ID: MacBookPro6,1

Chrome browser is no longer supported running in Mavericks. see [this article](https://www.trustedreviews.com/news/google-chrome-mavericks-3493700)
The report said one can use Firefox or Safari instead.  However, I had html links saved within the Chrome browser.  How can I extract the html links in it? Which directory should I start looking?

UPDATED: Thanks for everyone who help me to find the books, I ended up finding it using terminal application.  It is in the directory /Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1
/Bookmarks

Another way to look for the bookmarks is if you had sync the bookmarks to google, one can go to the www.google.com/bookmarks to retrieve the bookmark.

Comment: What is preventing you from updating to a more current OS?

Comment: I did use a more recent Mac OS Sierra by dual booting the machine, but I found better performance with the Mavericks OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear... When you say "I had html links saved within the Chrome browser.", by that do you mean that you had bookmarked various web pages by using the Chrome > Bookmarks > Bookmark This Page...  or Bookmark All Tabs...? If yes, then the file you want is the

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

file, and I believe it's in JSON format.

However, you'll need to use the Bookmark Manager in Firefox to import the data.

In Firefox, click Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks or just press: Shift-Command-B

From the Library window that opens, in the Toolbar, the last icon on the right click and select: Import Data from Another Browser...

Then walk through the Import Wizard making the appropriate selections along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has an option to import/export Bookmarks, just have to know where to look.

In Chrome go to the menu > Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager

A new tab opens, on the right side there is a secondary menu on the blue bookmarks bar, click it and select Export Bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  The problem is I cannot start Chrome Browser as it is EOL. I cannot reach the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you say. The problem is I cannot start Chrome Browser as it is EOL. I cannot reach the menu. – @g5thomas

You can still get it as Text file with all your saved url"s

It is located in ..

Open up "Finder" and "go to" ->Library ->Application Support ->Google ->Chrome -> Bookmarks

Comment: Thanks, this works too. i am more comfortable with the Terminal and Unix commands. I find the corresponding file, and then extract the url I needed.